# Node router returning response by itself

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is probably extremely simple but I am really confused by it.
When I hit my node /verify endpoint either via postman or the frontend, a 200 response from the backend is being sent back automatically when non 'response' values/functions are in the /verify endpoint.

For example, if I make the function extremely simple:

This will send a 200 response back, even though I don't appear to be setting 'response' anywhere.

```
router.post('/verify', (request, response, next) => {
  code = code.toUpperCase();
});
```

This won't send a 200 response back (and I don't think it should, as I'm not setting response to anything)

```
router.post('/verify', (request, response, next) => {
  const { code } = request.body;
  console.log(code);
});
```

Can anyone explain to me what is going on? I expect to need to reference response like the examples below to push a response back

```
response.status(401).send("Lorem ipsum");
```

or

```
response.json(token);
```

Thanks

Whole page (excluding other API calls which shouldn't affect this)

```
const poolArray = require('../../db');
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

router.post('/verify', (request, response, next) => {
  // let { code } = request.body; //if commented out will send 200 back automatically, if not commented out won't pass 200 back automatically
  code = code.toUpperCase();
})

module.exports = router;
```

My index.js:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT;

const { langleyUser, langleyHost, langleyDatabase, langleyPassword, langleyPort, onboardingUser, onboardingHost, onboardingDatabase, onboardingPassword, onboardingPort } = require('../secrets/db_configuration');

const langley = new Pool({ user: langleyUser, host: langleyHost, database: langleyDatabase, password: langleyPassword, port: langleyPort });
const onboarding = new Pool({ user: onboardingUser, host: onboardingHost, database: onboardingDatabase, password: onboardingPassword, port: onboardingPort });

const poolArray = {
    langley,
    onboarding
}

module.exports = poolArray;
```

Middleware

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = (request, response, next) => {
  try {
    console.log(' in check auth request');
    const decoded = jwt.verify(request.headers.authorization, 'bFm3Vp4Ga@cG6W');
    request.userData = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return response.status(404).json({
      message: 'Authentication failed'
    })
  }

};
```

Comment: I would expect the first snippet to crash since `code` is not defined anywhere. Express would handle this exception and normally send back a 500 error, not a 200 success. Can you show us your complete program that exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: Have updated code, not really sure what else I can add. Please let me know if there is a file that you want to see

Comment: Can you add the part where you register middlewares ? for example, `app.use(something)`

Comment: Have added it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe Express will return 200 OK (?) when the response is not specified. If you want to continue to another middleware layer then call `next()`.

Comment: OK thanks, maybe it's just expected behavior then. 
Though would an error in my code cause 200 to be sent? I'd have thought an error in the code would either not cause a response to be sent, or it sends a status error code.

Comment: @MattBerry An error in your code would cause Express to send `500 Internal Server Error`, and the request body would be the error message & it's stack trace, and you would see an error message & stack trace printed to the console.

Comment: That's not happening in my case. No error in console, and a 200 response is returned. 
Got me stumped.